# How to get Timestamp of UTC time with Golang?

Tags: go, timestamp, unix-timestamp

I want to convert UTC time string to unix timestamp.
I do this

```
fmt.Printf("%s %d\n", time.Now().String(), time.Now().Unix())
fmt.Printf("%s %s\n", time.Now().UTC().String(), time.Now().UTC().Unix())
```

But I got same unix timestamp `1499018765`

> 2017-07-02 20:06:05.5582802 +0200 CEST 1499018765
>
> 2017-07-02 18:06:05.791337 +0000 UTC 1499018765

Answer (score 98, accepted):

`Unix()` always returns the number of seconds elapsed since January 1, 1970 UTC. So it does not matter whether you give it `time.Now()` or `time.Now().UTC()`, it is the same UTC time, just in different places on Earth. What you get as the result is correct.

Comment: could you please explain the frase " it is the same UTC time, just in different places on Earth" UTC wasn't meant to be universal? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pOGL7oqZqEc

Comment: A given moment or point in time is a unique instance which can be represented in various ways, according to the point of reference. E.g. some event taking place at noon time somewhere where the timezone is GMT-2 would be referred to or represented as 15 hours (3pm) by someone on GMT+1 timezone, as 17 hours (5pm) by someone on GMT+3 timezone and so on. So, different references to a single point in time. I hope this helps somewhat.